# laravel_session id in http header is too long?

Tags: session, laravel-5

I develop with laravel 5, and I find laravel session id is too long, and I want to change it by myself, who can tell me how ? 
[image]

Comment: laravel_session is too long

Answer (score 0):

This cookie is set by Laravel inner logic and the session cookie is encrypted.

If you want to make it shorter then you need to patch the Laravel Session classes which is not advisable.